# How to mount an arbitrary directory and allow a user to umunt it?

Tags: mount, sudo, tmpfs

I use a script to mount a temporary directory:

```bsh
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=5G,nr_inodes=10k,mode=0777,user tmpfs tempdir
```

The script is runned from dozens directories, that probably means that I can't use `fstab`. When the script does its job, I want my memory to be freed as soon as possible. But the `umount` command requires `sudo`, that prompts for a password. Thus the memory remains busy until I enter the correct password. How to overcome it?

Possible solutions (no success trying them):

a) Use `user` or `users` option for `mount` (see above) - looks like I'm doing that wrong

b) Use another command instead of `umount` or of `mount` (`fusermount -u` and `umount -l -f` did not help)

c) Somehow tell `sudo` not to ask for password again *in this terminal* - no idea how.

Comment: Is this a single tempdir or dozens of similar tempdirs?

Comment: This is a very common question: "How can i allow a user to run a command as root without asking for  their password?".   The answer is always the same: "Write a script to do exactly that thing and configure sudoers to allow the user to run it with NOPASSWD:".    The script should do as little as possible, the bare minimum to do just the part of the job that requires root privs, and (for security reasons) preferably not take arguments or user input.

Comment: In your case, you probably want two scripts - one to mount the tmpfs, and the other to unmount it.   or one script that takes just one argument (which can be either "mount" or "unmount" - anything else should trigger an error and exit immediately...an argument for deciding which of two hard-coded options to run is relatively safe, but passing a user-supplied argument directly to `mount` or some other command is potentially very dangerous).

Comment: @JeremyBoden, there are dozens of similar tempdirs mounted to various locations